# Change focus by Enter don't work with Telerik RadDropDownList

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, telerik

I used following code to change the tab order by pressing Enter key , and it works great on any objects of my form.But when I changed the AutoCompleteMode property of my RadDropDownList to "SuggestAppend" , then
when I press Enter on RaddropDown the tab order not changed and it stay on this control !!!! plz help to handle this problem.

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && (int)m.WParam == 13)
            {
                this.ProcessTabKey(true);
            }
  return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete example of the case?

Comment: Dear @checho ,by using posted code I can use Enter as act like Tab key on win form app, but the problem is it works great on any object except Telerik RadDropDownList when set it's Autocompletemode="SuggestAppend" properties !!!

Comment: As I mentioned, I was not able to reproduce the behavior you mention. I have captured a video with my tests: http://screencast.com/t/Xf2L0w18XGU

Comment: @checho, I see it works fine for you but , it is not working for me , as I tested again with new project like what you did , but when I set to Suggest Append it doesn't work for me !!!

Comment: Thank @checho , I found the problem it is related to return line , as you used only "true" but mine was "base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m)"
and whern I changed it to true it works like a charm :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && (int)m.WParam == 13)
        {
            this.ProcessTabKey(true);
        }
        //return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);/////problem was with this line and when changet to following line it works Great !!
        **return true;** 
    }
```

Thanks to @checho , about your video 
[VIDEO](http://screencast.com/t/Xf2L0w18XGU)